# Multi-line function calls with strings in python

Tags: python

I have a function call in python 2.7:

```
execute_cmd('/sbin/ip addr flush dev '
             + args.interface
             + ' && '
             + '/sbin/ifdown '
             + args.interface
             + ' ; '
             + '/sbin/ifup '
             + args.interface
             + ' && '
             + '/sbin/ifconfig | grep '
             + args.interface)
```

This is running fine, but `pylint` is complaining with the following warning messages:

```
C:220, 0: Wrong continued indentation (remove 1 space).
                    + args.interface
                   |^ (bad-continuation)
C:221, 0: Wrong continued indentation (remove 1 space).
                    + ' && '
                   |^ (bad-continuation)
C:222, 0: Wrong continued indentation (remove 1 space).
                    + '/sbin/ifconfig | grep '
                   |^ (bad-continuation)
.
.
.
```

What is the correct way to call a function in python with string argument(s) which spans across multiple lines?.

Comment: Ignore `pylint`.

Comment: But I want the code to be in correct pep8 style

Comment: It is once you apply the [most important rule in PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds).

Comment: Then use the operator before the line break

Comment: Why not format the string before passing it to the function? Solves your problem and is much better readable.

Comment: Yes, will pass the string after forming it properly instead of forming it during the function call. Good one.

Comment: @Vijay47 Remove 1 space.

Answer (score 1):

Pylint tells you exactly what to do, remove one space:

```
execute_cmd('/sbin/ip addr flush dev '
            + args.interface
            + ' && '
            + '/sbin/ifdown '
            + args.interface
            + ' ; '
            + '/sbin/ifup '
            + args.interface
            + ' && '
            + '/sbin/ifconfig | grep '
            + args.interface)
```

Also, you could use string formatting, for example:

```
command_line = '/sbin/ip addr flush dev {0} && /sbin/ifdown {0} ; /sbin/ifup {0} && {0} /sbin/ifconfig | grep {0}'\
    .format(args.interface)
```

Comment: I am using atom IDE. When I try to remove 1 space, its removing 4.

Comment: Well that's a different question: 'How to make atom IDE indent python properly ?' You should ask a new question.

Comment: The second code may span more than 80 characters which breaks the pep8 rule.

Answer (score 0):

[PEP 8 states](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) that you can also start a long argument list (or anything within brackets, really) at the next line with one extra indentation level:

```
execute_cmd(
    '/sbin/ip addr flush dev ' +
    args.interface +
    ' && ' +
    '/sbin/ifdown ' +
    args.interface +
    ' ; ' +
    '/sbin/ifup ' +
    args.interface +
    ' && ' + 
    '/sbin/ifconfig | grep ' +
    args.interface
)
```

As I said in my comment, [binary operators should be put at the end of a line break](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#should-a-line-break-before-or-after-a-binary-operator), not at the start of a new one.

---

What you can also do is use an `fstring` (python >3.6) and just drop the `+`s:

```
execute_cmd(
    f'/sbin/ip addr flush dev {args.interface} && /sbin/ifdown'
    f' {args.interface} ; /sbin/ifup {args.interface} && '
    f'/sbin/ifconfig | grep {args.interface}'
)
```

The same with the `.format` function (from python .. 2.6 onwards I think?):

```
execute_cmd(
    '/sbin/ip addr flush dev {0} && /sbin/ifdown' +
    ' {0} ; /sbin/ifup {0} && ' +
    '/sbin/ifconfig | grep {0}'.format(args.interface)
)
```

Comment: I am using python 2.7. The formatting solution with f'..' should work, but in 3.xx+

Comment: `fstring` s most definitely do not work in python 2.7, but using `string.format()` does pretty much exactly the same thing with a little different syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to highlight the position of `+`, as pointed out in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57074416/17090791)

Best practice:

```
income = (gross_wages
          + taxable_interest)
```

Anti-pattern: (In PEP8, this is W504 line break after binary operator)

```
income = (gross_wages +
          taxable_interest)
```